# SQL Server 2012/2014 Express setup.exe fails on WS2012 R2 when run in quiet mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express, sql-server-2012-express, sql-server-2014-express

I downloaded `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` and extracted its content (`/X` option) into a temp folder. I then attempted to run `setup.exe` in a quiet mode. Unfortunately the setup failed.

Here is the command line that I used to install the server and the output it generated:

```
C:\temp>%temp%\sqltemp\Setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLEngine 
       /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS 
       /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
       /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators" 
       /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
       /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS


Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2014 12.00.2000.08
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

The following error occurred:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> Error result: -2068774911
>      Result facility code: 1201
>      Result error code: 1
>
> Please review the summary.txt log for further details

I could not find `summary.txt` log file when the installation failed. However, I found `SqlSetup.txt` with the following content (excerpts):

```
[...]
02/02/2017 16:56:43.126 Attempting to get execution timestamp
02/02/2017 16:56:43.126 Timestamp: 20170202_165642
02/02/2017 16:56:43.126 Attempting to run user requested action from media ScenarioEngine.exe
02/02/2017 16:56:43.126 Attempting to launch process C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\sqltemp\x64\ScenarioEngine.exe
02/02/2017 16:56:46.423 Process returned exit code: 0x84B10001
02/02/2017 16:56:46.423 Media ScenarioEngine.exe returned exit code: 0x84B10001
02/02/2017 16:56:46.423 Attempting to load .Net security policy file C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\\CONFIG\security.config
02/02/2017 16:56:46.423 Attempting to remove .Net security code group node 
[...]
```

I tried both SQL Server Express 2012 and 2014 and both failed with the same error.

When I ran the same `setup.exe` without any parameters (i.e. not in a quiet mode) then the installation worked fine.

Does anyone know what could cause the quiet mode to fail?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution for this question?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to use "/FEATURES=SQL"
2. Try to use SQL Security: "/SAPWD=MyStrongSAPassword2016 /SECURITYMODE=SQL"
3. Create local SQL admin account and use it within setup line (Example: WinCore\CoreAdmin + Password: LocalAdmin2016) 
   See sample code, which works for standard/enterprise:

   d:\setup.exe /ACTION=Install /Q /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /SAPWD=MyStrongSAPassword2016 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /FEATURES=SQL /SQLSVCACCOUNT="WinCore\CoreAdmin" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="LocalAdmin2016" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="WinCore\CoreAdmin" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="WinCore\CoreAdmin" /AGTSVCPASSWORD="LocalAdmin2016" /ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS="WinCore\CoreAdmin"